# For loop - syntax error

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I've been staring at this for half an hour and can't find my error. I just have to make a simple for loop that can print something onto the console.

```
for(var i=0;i<4;i+1){
    console.log(i);
}
```

It also is asking for a while loop and a do/while loop. I haven't done those yet, but I don't think that's the error. It says: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: Or the more ubiquitous:  i++

Comment: `i + 1` would not change the value of `i` after the steps

Comment: I tried all of those; nothing happened. I guess not doing the while and do/while loops is my problem?

Comment: Suggestion for next times: using browser's debugger may help you find the errors.

Comment: The code shown does not contain a syntax error. It will, however, result in an endless loop because the `i` variable is set to `0` and then never changed. The "Unexpected token ILLEGAL" error you quote doesn't make sense for the code shown - do you have more code that is not shown?

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes, I'm using Codeacademy to learn javascript and it's asking me to form for, while, and do/while loops. I was getting infinite loops so I was going through each one by one and //'d the others. That might be my error.

Comment: I suggest to [learn how to debug JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) :)

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is incorrect. You have to add the `1` to the `i`, which you are not currently doing.

```
for(var i=0; i<4; i+=1){
    console.log(i);
}
```

The classic way, of course is to just do, but I think the first one is more elegant and passes JSLint (which is, of course, the only right way to write javascript).

```
for(var i=0; i<4; i++){
    console.log(i);
}
```

If you want your loop to fully pass JSLint, you can do as follows:

```
var i; // at the top of your function
// ...
for (i = 0; i < 4; i += 1) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: _"and passes JSLint"_ - Does putting `var` inside the `for` pass JSLint?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I was just referring to the `i += 1`. When I write a loop, I put the `var i` outside the loop.

Comment: Technically the syntax is *correct* but the logic is incorrect. *"which is, of course, the only right way to write javascript"* That's very opinionated, isn't it? ;)

Comment: No! I'm being completely objective! :). What do you mean by the logic being incorrect, I'd love to correct my answer.

Comment: I mean that if the syntax was incorrect, the engine would actually throw a syntax error. `i+1` is valid syntax, but it doesn't do what the OP intends to do (increment `i`), thus it's a logic error. I can also be very pedantic so feel free to ignore me ;)

Comment: My understanding is that you are, in fact, adding `i + 1`, but that result is not getting added to the `i` variable, which is why, if you run this script, the `console.log` always outputs `0`.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. Then ignore my previous comment. Agreed, yes it's not a syntax error.

Comment: I guess I never said it was a syntax error, but that his syntax is incorrect which is semantically valid considering his intentions. haha

Answer (score 0):

or how 'bout:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 4; )
    console.log(i++);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run your code in Chrome console, and I think your code have no SyntaxError, but it will cause en endless loop.

If you want to run a four loop, you'd better change the code like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<4; i+=1){
    console.log(i);
}
```